# OpenGL PingPong shader does not work. I can't see why

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

My code looks like this:

```
[... removed, look at new code further down ...]
```

The rest of the class is not relevant (I think). The shader is working, but the swapping does not. I want to switch the source texture and rendertarget every frame.
I guess I'm making some mistake with the frame buffer, but I can't pinpoint it. Any ideas?

Update: Okay I made some changes to the code now, and now I get a black screen.
I'm rendering two quads, first I render between Start() and End(), then I call BindTexture and render to screen. (At least that's what I'm trying)

```
void PingPongShader::Init(int width, int height, const char* vertexShaderName, const char* fragmentShaderName)
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    began = false;
    GLuint frameBuffer;
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
    textures = new GLuint[2];
    textures[0] = GenerateTexture();
    textures[1] = GenerateTexture();
    current = 0;
    shader = LoadShader(vertexShaderName, fragmentShaderName);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
void PingPongShader::Start()
{
    if(!began)
    {
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[abs(current-1)]);
        //buffer
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer);
        GLenum drawBuffers[1] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
        glDrawBuffers(1, drawBuffers);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[current], 0);

        glUseProgram(shader);
        if(paramCallback != NULL)
            paramCallback(shader);
        began = true;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Could not call Start(). Did you forget to call End() ?");
    }
}
void PingPongShader::End()
{
    if(began)
    {

        glUseProgram(0);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        current = abs(current-1);
        began = false;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Could not call End(). Did you forget to call Start() ?");
    }
}
void PingPongShader::BindCurrentTexture()
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[current]);
}
```

Comment: By the way, you are using shaders... `glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D)` does absolutely nothing in the programmable pipeline. The same goes for disabling this state. Unless you are using fixed-function fragment processing this is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be confusing texture **units** and texture **names**. Texture units correspond to the sampler variables in your shader code and range from 0 to `GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` minus one. You can pick an image unit (say 0) and set that value to the shader uniform variable. This is also the value you would pass to `glActiveTexture`, before calling `glBindTexture` with a texture **name** (the `a` and `b` variables in your code).

Comment: Yes, I realized that. I made several changes to the code, but it still doesn't seem to work.